# Simple Xamarin Forms text binding in code behind not working

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I have a very simple code sample to try to test an aspect of data binding. However, I cannot get it to work, and I'm hoping someone can point out to me what I'm doing wrong.

In the cs code-behind file I have this:

```
string textSample = "This is a test!";
BindingContext = this;
```

And in the xaml file:

```
<Label Text = "{Binding Path=textSample}" />
```

When I run the code, the label does not display anything.

I'm obviously missing something, but I can't see what.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

You can only bind to public `properties`

```
public string textSample { get { return "This is a test!"; }};
BindingContext = this;
```

`Path` is not needed:

```
<Label Text = "{Binding textSample}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
public string textSample {get;set;} = "This is a test!";
```